# Check if an element is common between 2 arrays and then assign values from it

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular 8 application, I have 2 arrays:

```
array1 = [{
        "SubType": "2|3|4|5|6",
    },
    {
        "SubType": "2",
    },
    {
        "SubType": "3|4",
    },
    {
        "SubType": "6",
    },
    {
        "SubType": "3|6",
    },
]
```

&

```
array2 = [{
        "id": 2,
        "type": "1",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "type": "5",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "type": "4",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "type": "3",
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "type": "2",
    }
]
```

I am trying to check each `"SubType"` in `array1` and see if that element(id) is present in `array2` and if present assign its `"type"` to a variable. `"SubType"` is | separated which I and converting to an array using `array1..split('|')`. This when assigning to a variable will need to be comma separated.  I tried using array filter but I am not able to find a way to loop thorough the second array. Can anyone help?

```
array1.forEach(reg => {
    if (reg.SubType) {
        let subTypeTemp = reg.SubType.split('|');
        let tempVariable = subTypeTemp.some(ele => {
            let stringToassign = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
                if (ele == array2[i].id) {
                    stringToassign += array2[i].type + ",";
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Hi Nina, the final result I want is something like "2,3,4"

Comment: What is `element(id)`?

Comment: I meant element

Answer (score 2):

You could take a `Map` and prevent looping `array2` over and over for getting `type` of a wanted `id`.

```js
var array1 = [{ SubType: "2|3|4|5|6" }, { SubType: "2" }, { SubType: "3|4" }, { SubType: "6" }, { SubType: "3|6" }],
    array2 = [{ id: 2, type: "1" }, { id: 3, type: "5" }, { id: 4, type: "4" }, { id: 5, type: "3" }, { id: 6, type: "2" }],
    types = new Map(array2.map(({ id, type }) => [id.toString(), type])),
    result = array1.map(({ SubType }) => SubType
        .split('|')
        .map(Map.prototype.get, types)
        .join()
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am expecting 5 results for each element in arrray1. Thats why I am using a forEach loop.

Comment: please add a **complete** wanted result.

Comment: The result would be  "1,5,4,3,2" , "1", "5,4", "2", "5,2"

Comment: Thanks for your help Nina, I looks great, let me try it out on my code

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    SubType: "2|3|4|5|6"
  },
  { SubType: "2" },
  { SubType: "3|4" },
  { SubType: "6" },
  { SubType: "3|6" }
];

const array2 = [
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "1"
  },
  { id: 3, type: "5" },
  { id: 4, type: "4" },
  { id: 5, type: "3" },
  { id: 6, type: "2" }
];

const array2Obj = array2.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({
    ...acc,
    [curr.id]: curr.type
  }),
  {}
);

const types = [];
array1.forEach(item => {
  const sub_types = item.SubType.split("|");
  sub_types.forEach(st => {
    if (st in array2Obj) {
      types.push(array2Obj[st]);
    }
  });
});

const types_str = [...new Set(types)].join(',');

console.log("types", types_str);
```